# PySpark replace multiple words in string column based on values in array column

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe that contains a string column with text of varied lengths, then I have an array column where each element is a struct with specified word, index, start position and end position in the text column. I want to replace words in the text column, that is in the array.

It looks like this:

```text
- id:integer
- text:string
- text_entity:array
  - element:struct
    - word:string
    - index:integer
    - start:integer
    - end:integer
```

`text` example could be:

```
"I talked with Christian today at Cafe Heimdal last Wednesday"
```

`text_entity` example could be:

```
[{"word": "Christian", "index":4, "start":14, "end":23}, {"word": "Heimdal", "index":8, "start":38, "end":45}]
```

I then want to change the `text` to have the words at the above indexes replaced to:

```
"I talked with (BLEEP) today at Cafe (BLEEP) last Wednesday"
```

My initial approach was to explode the array and then do a `regex_replace`, but then there is the problem of collecting the text and merging them. And it seems like it would take a lot of operations. And I would like to not use UDFs, as performance is quite important. `regex_replace` also has the problem that it might match sub-strings, and that would not be okay. Therefore ideally the index, start, or end is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `aggregate` function on `text_entity` array with splitted `text` column as the initial value like this:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

jsonSting = """{"id":1,"text":"I talked with Christian today at Cafe Heimdal last Wednesday","text_entity":[{"word":"Christian","index":4,"start":14,"end":23},{"word":"Heimdal","index":8,"start":38,"end":45}]}"""
df = spark.read.json(spark.sparkContext.parallelize([jsonSting]))

df1 = df.withColumn(
    "text",
    F.array_join(
        F.expr(r"""aggregate(
                  text_entity, 
                  split(text, " "), 
                  (acc, x) -> transform(acc, (y, i) -> IF(i=x.index, '(BLEEP)', y))
           )"""),
        " "
    )
)

df1.show(truncate=False)
#+---+----------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+
#|id |text                                                      |text_entity                                   |
#+---+----------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+
#|1  |I talked with (BLEEP) today at Cafe (BLEEP) last Wednesday|[{23, 4, 14, Christian}, {45, 8, 38, Heimdal}]|
#+---+----------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Do you think its possible to use the position to replace the words instead? Problem here being that the name Christian might appear multiple times in the text, but should only be 'bleeped' in one instance, not all of them.

Comment: @cenh then you can use array positions to replace the element at `index`. by first splitting the `text` column by space to get an array column then use aggregate. Please see above update.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this answer using `regexp_replace`. Problem with using `regex_replace` however is that it will replace all occurrences, which is not the intention as a word could appear multiple time in the text, and only some of the occurrences should be `bleeped`

```
df = df.withColumn("temp_entities", F.expr(f"transform(text_entity, (x, i) -> x.word)")) \
    .withColumn("temp_entities", F.array_distinct("temp_entities")) \
    .withColumn("regex_expression", F.concat_ws("|", "temp_entities")) \
    .withColumn("regex_expression", F.concat(F.lit("\\b("), F.col("regex_expression"), F.lit(")\\b"))) \
    .withColumn("text", F.when(F.size("text_entity") > 0, F.expr("regexp_replace(text, regex_expression, '(BLEEP)')")).otherwise(F.col(text)))
```

It removes duplicates, and only applies `regexp_replace` if there are at least 1 entity. Probably not the most elegant solution, and will `bleep` all occurrences of the word. Ideally the position should be used.